# Convert C# code to F# code: lists manipulation

Tags: list, f#, c#-to-f#

Good morning at all,
first I present myself: my name is Mattia and I'm a student in Computer Science.

I've a problem with three function that I've already implement in two other programming language (C# and Python), using imperative loop like for and while, but what I've to do is to convert them in the recursive style.

The function in C# are:

- resetList: given two list, the method initialize the counters inside the object of first list, and put the new object in the second list.

  ```
  public static List<myObject> resetList(List<myObject> inList, List<myObject> outList, bool flag)
  {
      foreach (myObject myObj in inList)
      {
          myObj.FirstCounter= 0;

          if (flag)
              myObj.SecondCounter= 0;
          outList.Add(myObj );
      }
      return outList;
  }
  ```
- randomIntList: given the number of integer to generate (n), the method return a list with n random integer choosen between 1 and 56.

  ```
  int i = 0;
  while (i < n)
  {
      int randomNumber = randomizer.Next(1, 56 + 1);

      if (!listOut.Contains(randomNumber))
      {
          listOut[I] = randomNumber;
          i++;
      }
  }
  ```
- compareRule: given two custom object, the method find the first equal character between them.

  ```
  int index = myObject1.Index;
  char myChar = myObject1.getChar();

  while ((index < 6) && !(myObject2.getChar().Equals(myChar)))
  {
      index++;
      myChar= myObject1.getCharAt(index);
  }

  myObject1.Counter++;
  ```

I can convert them in imperative loop style but not in recursive style, for example:

- resetList:

  ```
  (Imperative version)

  let resetList inList flag =
      let mutable outList = []

      for myObj in inList do
          if flag = true then
              outList <- outList @ [new myObject(myObj.Index, 0, myObj.Chars, 0)]
          else
              outList <- outList @ [new myObject(myObj.Index, 0, myObj.Chars, myObj.Counter)]
  outList

  (Recursive version: try...)

  let resetList listaIn flag =
      let mutable outList = []

      let rec resetListRec inList =
          match inList with
          | [] -> outList
          | head :: tail ->
              if flag = true then
                  outList <- outList @ [new myObject(head.Index, 0, head.Chars, 0)]
              else
                  outList <- outList @ [new myObject(head.Index, 0, head.Chars, head.Counter)]
      resetListRec tail
  ```

Thank you at all, Mattia.

**Solutions:**

- resetList:

  ```
  let rec resetList list flag =
      match list with
      | [] -> []
      | (myObj : myObject) :: myObjs ->
          let myObj =
              if flag then
                 new myObject(myObj.Index, 0, myObj.Chars, 0)
              else
                 new myObject(myObj.Index, 0, myObj.Chars, myObjs.Counter)

      myObj :: (resetList myObjs flag)
  ```
- findCharEqual:

  ```
  let rec findCharEqual index (myObj1 : myObject) (myObj2 : myObject) = 
      let char1 = myObj1.GetChar()
      let char2 = myObj1.GetChar(index)

      if (index < 6) && (char1 <> char2) then
          findCharEqual (index + 1) myObj1 myObj2
      else
          new myObject(myObj2.Index, index, myObj2.Chars, myObj2.Counter + 1)
  ```
- randomList:

  ```
  let randomList n = 
      let randomizer = new Random()
      Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> randomizer.Next(1, MAX_N + 1))
      |> Seq.distinct 
      |> Seq.take n
      |> Seq.toList
  ```

**Update:** Now I'm working with this (last) while loop that I'm trying to translate in recursive form.

```
(... declaration of listIn, listOut, listTemp...)

while (listOut.Length < n) do
    let mutable myObj1 = new myObject(0, 0, Array.empty, 0)
    let mutable myObj2 = new myObject(0, 0, Array.empty,0)

    if (listIn.Length = 0) then
        if (listOut.Length > 1) then
            myObj1 <- listOut.[listOut.Length - 2]

            myObj2 <- new myObject(listOut.[listOut.Length - 1].Index, listOut.[listOut.Length - 1].Char + 1, listOut.[listOut.Length - 1].Chars, listOut.[listOut.Length - 1].Counter)

            listOut <- removeObject (listOut.Length - 1) listOut

            if (myObj2.Counter < 2) then
                listIn <- listIn @ resetObject listTemp false
                listTemp <- List.empty<myObject>

            else
                myObj1 <- new myObject(listOut.Head.Index, listOut.Head.Char + 1, listOut.Head.Chars, listOut.Head.Counter)

                listOut <- List.empty<myObject>
                listOut <- listOut @ [myObj1]

                listIn <- listIn @ resetObject listTemp true

                listTemp <- List.empty<myObject>

                myObj2 <- listIn.Head
                listIn <- removeObject 0 listIn
        else
            myObj1 <- listOut.[listOut.Length - 1]
            myObj2 <- listIn.Head

            listIn <- removeObject 0 listIn

        let mutable indFxDx = myObj2.Char
        myObj2 <- fingEqualChar indFxDx myObj1 myObj2

        if (myObj2.Char < 6) then
            if (myObj1.leftChar = myObj2.rightChar) then
                listOut <- listOut @ [myObj2]

                if (listTemp.Length > 0) then
                    listIn <- listIn @ resetObject listTemp false
                    listTemp <- List.empty<myObject>

        else
            listTemp <- listTemp @ [myObj2]
```

(... A not working solution ...)

```
(... declaration of listIn, listOut, listTemp...)
let rec findSolution i =
    if i < n then
        (... function atre the while declaration, to the end...)
    findSolution (i + 1)

listOut <- findSolution 0
```

The problem is that I need to modify three lists and in the recursive style this is not possible, sombody have any idea?

Mattia

Answer (score 2):

If you're learning F# then it is useful to first write a few recursive functions yourself. Later, you'll learn that many of them match some existing pattern and you'll use functions like `List.map` (as in Ankur's solution).

So, to write your `resetList` function recursively, you would do something like this:

```
let rec resetList inList flag =
    match inList with
    | [] -> []  // For empty list, we can only return emtpy list
    | x::xs ->  
        // For non-empty list, create an object depending on the 'flag'
        let obj =
          if flag then new myObject(myObj.Index, 0, myObj.Chars, 0)
          else new myObject(myObj.Index, 0, myObj.Chars, myObj.Counter)
        // Process the rest of the list (recursively) and then add 
        // object we just created to the front
        obj :: (resetList xs flag)
```

This implementation is not *tail-recursive*, which means that it does something after calling `restList` recursively (it appends value to the front). This can be a problem if you're processing long lists, but you probably don't need to worry at the moment.

For more information & some introduction to [working with functional lists, see this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297099.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Below is something that you can do:

```
let resetList inList outList flag = 
    outList @ inList |> List.map (fun i -> i.FirstCounter = 0;
                                           match flag with
                                           | true -> i.SecondCounter = 0; i
                                           | _ -> i)


let randomList n = 
    let rnd = new Random()
    seq {while true do yield rnd.Next(1,56)}
    |> Seq.distinct 
    |> Seq.take n
    |> Seq.toList 


let findCharEqual obj1 obj2 = 
    let c = obj1.getChar()
    let d = obj2.getChar()
    if c = d then
        c
    else 
        findCharEqual obj1 obj2
```

Think about higher order function before thinking iteratively or recursively

Answer (score 0):

Your first function just iterates over a list copying it and performing some side effects on the objects in it. There is no point in copying F# lists because they are immutable so the idiomatic translation is:

```
let resetList inList flag =
  for o in inList do
    o.FirstCounter <- 0
    if flag then
      o.SecondCounter <- 0
  inList
```

You could also use `Seq.iter` or `List.iter` or hand-roll a recursive loop like the one in `List.iter`.

While loops are equivalent to recursive functions that execute the body and recurse when the predicate is satisfied:

```
let rec loop i =
  if i < n then
    let randomNumber = randomizer.Next(1, 56 + 1)
    if listOut.Contains randomNumber then
      listOut.[i] <- randomNumber
      loop (i + 1)
```

Same for the next `while` loop:

```
let rec loop index myChar =
  if index < 6 && not (myObject2.getChar().Equals myChar) then
    myObject1.getCharAt index |> loop (index + 1)
myObject1.getChar() |> loop myObject1.Index
myObject1.Counter <- myObject1.Counter + 1
```