# Convert C# to Prolog code: recursive while loop

Tags: c#, recursion, prolog

Good evening at all, after solving my previous problem explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227919/convert-c-code-to-f-code-lists-manipulation%20here), I've a few last problem with the Prolog version:

- compare rule: given two custom object, the method find the first equal character between them.

  ```
  int index = myObject1.Index;
  char myChar = myObject1.getChar();

  while ((index < 6) && !(myObject2.getChar().Equals(myChar)))
  {
      index++;
      myChar= myObject1.getCharAt(index);
  }

  myObject1.Counter++;
  ```

(A solution that doesn't works)

```
[Closing rule]

compare_rule(I,Obj1,Obj2) :-
getChar(Obj2,Char2),
getChar(Obj1,Char1),
Char1 == Char2;
I == 6.

[Recursive rule]

compare_rule(I,Obj1,Obj2) :-
getChar(Obj2,Char2),
getChar(Obj1,Char1),
    I < 6, Char1 == Char2,
    I1 is I+1,
    compare_rule(I1,Obj1,Obj2).
```

The rule should return Obj2 with the new index and a counter incremented by 1: how can I do it?

Tahnk you, very much,
Mattia

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question entirely.

- How are your objects defined? In particular, what does getChar() return?
- Why do the objects occur in your Prolog code? Prolog isn't object-oriented.

Whatever, given to Strings `S0` and `S1`, `common(S0, S1, I0, I1)` unifies `I0` and `I1` with the positions of the first common character of `S0` and `S1`, respectively. If there is none, it fails. You may add `I0 < 6` to only get solutions for `S0`'s first 6 characters.

```
common([C|_], S1, 1, I) :-
    contains(C, S1, I).
common([C|S0], S1, I0, I1) :-
    \+ contains(C, S1, I),
    common(S0, S1, I, I1),
    I0 is I + 1.

contains(C, [C|_], 1).
contains(C, [C0|T], I) :-
    C \= C0,
    contains(C, T, I0),
    I is I0 + 1.
```

I guess you shouldn't try that much to *convert* C# to Prolog. Instead, rather think about what the C# program does and build a Prolog program that has the same effect. They are to different to convert code from one to other and get reasonable code in the target language.